# Dynamically generating HTML check boxes via JS with CSS styling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

It's been hours since I am trying to code a simple HTML/CSS/JS page but, I couldn't be able to find the solution.

Basically, I just need to do this:

[image]

I am trying to generate a new checkbox with CSS styles like border, padding etc but, the CSS styles aren't working no matter what I do.

Below is the code that I'm working with:

```css
 

    function addItem() {

    var text = document.getElementById('texto');

    if (text.value == "") {
        alert("Please enter something first!");
    } else {

        var ul = document.getElementById('ul'); //ul
        //var li = document.createElement('li');//li

        var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
        checkbox.type = "checkbox";
        checkbox.value = 1;
        checkbox.name = "todo[]";
        //checkbox.className = "cb";
        //checkbox.style.border = "1px solid black";


        checkbox.setAttribute("style", "background-color:red; font-size:2em; border: 1px solid black");

        /*var att = document.createAttribute("style");
         att.value = "border: 1px solid black;";
         checkbox.setAttributeNode(att);*/


        //var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName("H1")[0];

        //document.getElementsByClassName("cb").style.backgroundColor = "red";

        ul.appendChild(checkbox);


        ul.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text.value));
        //ul.appendChild(ul); 

    }

}
var button = document.getElementById('btn');
button.onclick = addItem;
```

```html
<html>
 <head>

 </head>
 <body>

<button type="button" id="btn">Add Milestones</button>
<input type="text" id="texto">

<div id="ul" style="padding: 20px;">
 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Share your CSS. You should always styles your elements with css. Even if elements are dynamically added, CSS will be applied.

Comment: You should put you checkbox and the labels in a separate box (like a div), this way you can add padding to the div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don t think that it is the best solution , but this works

```js
 function addItem() {

        var text = document.getElementById('texto');

        if (text.value == "") {
            alert("Please enter something first!");
        } else {

            var ul = document.getElementById('ul'); //ul
            //var li = document.createElement('li');//li

            var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
            checkbox.type = "checkbox";
            checkbox.value = 1;
            checkbox.name = "todo[]";
            //checkbox.className = "cb";
            //checkbox.style.border = "1px solid black";

            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.appendChild(checkbox);
            div.setAttribute("class", "check");
            /*var att = document.createAttribute("style");
             att.value = "border: 1px solid black;";
             checkbox.setAttributeNode(att);*/


            //var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName("H1")[0];

            //document.getElementsByClassName("cb").style.backgroundColor = "red";

            ul.appendChild(div);

            div.appendChild(ul.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text.value)));
            
            //ul.appendChild(ul);

        }

    }
    var button = document.getElementById('btn');
    button.onclick = addItem;
```

```css
 .check {
            background-color: red;
            font-size: 2em;
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 10px;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

</head>
<body>
<button type="button" id="btn">Add Milestones</button>
<input type="text" id="texto">

<div id="ul" style="padding: 20px;">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function addItem(){  
    var text = document.getElementById('texto');
    
    if ( text.value == "" ) {
        alert("Please enter something first!");
    } else {
        
        var ul = document.getElementById('ul'); //ul
        //var li = document.createElement('li');//li
        
        var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
        checkbox.type = "checkbox";
        checkbox.value = 1;
        checkbox.name = "todo[]";
        //checkbox.className = "cb";
        //checkbox.style.border = "1px solid black";
        var label = document.createElement('label');
        label.append(checkbox);
        label.setAttribute("style", "background-color:red; font-size:2em; border: 1px solid black");
        
        /*var att = document.createAttribute("style");
        att.value = "border: 1px solid black;";
        checkbox.setAttributeNode(att);*/

        
        //var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName("H1")[0];
        
        //document.getElementsByClassName("cb").style.backgroundColor = "red";

        ul.appendChild(label);
        
        
        ul.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text.value));
        //ul.appendChild(ul); 
    
    }
        
}
var button = document.getElementById('btn');
button.onclick = addItem;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

</head>
<body>
<button type="button" id="btn">Add Milestones</button>
<input type="text" id="texto">

<div id="ul" style="padding: 20px;">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```